# How to access object of an object returned by json

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

in a little laravel application I'm working on I'm returning data from an ajax request like this:

```
return response ()->json ( $subject::where('id', $subject->id)->with('division')->get(['id', 'name']));
```

This returned something quite like an object that have nested objects. This how my results looks when I log it to the console.

[image]

I want to get the name and id of the subject details returned, which in this case is **History** and **8**. Also I want to be able to access the division array and properties of the object it has.

I do this to log the name of the subject `console.log(data.name)` but in returned I get:

> undefined

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `[Object]` output indicates that the value is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects, which has one property (`division`) - which contains another array. So you have to access the array indices

```
console.log(data[0].division[0].name);
```

Comment: @tyrneJV thanks so much I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the object structure we see that this is an array of elements, so it should be `data[0].name` to fetch `History` text

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `data` is your entire object.
Try `data[0].name`

Comment: thanks for your help